# How to extract multiples tables from one PDF file using Pandas and tabula-py

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdf, tabula

Can someone help me to extract multiples tables from **ONE** pdf file. I have 5 pages, every page have a table with same header column exp:

**Table exp in every page**

```
student  Score Rang
Alex     50     23
Julia    80     12
Mariana  94     4
```

I want to extract all this tables in one dataframe, First i did

```
df = tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages='all',multiple_tables=True)
```

But i got a messy output so i try this lines of code that looks like this :

```
[student  Score Rang
Alex     50     23
Julia    80     12
Mariana  94     4 ,student  Score Rang
Maxim    43     34
Nourah   93     5]
```

so i edited my code like this
import pandas as pd
import tabula

```
    file_path = "filePath.pdf"
    
    # read my file
    df1 = tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages=1,multiple_tables=True)
    df2 = tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages=2,multiple_tables=True)
    df3 = tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages=3,multiple_tables=True)
    df4 = tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages=3,multiple_tables=True)
    df5 = tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages=5,multiple_tables=True)
```

It give me a dataframe for each table but i don't how to regroup it into one single dataframe and any other solution to avoid repeating the line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation of tabula](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf), `read_pdf` returns a list when passed the `multiple_table=True` option.

Thus, you can use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on its output to concatenate the dataframes:

```
df = pd.concat(tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages='all',multiple_tables=True))
```

Comment: I tried this too, but i got an error `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Comment: what is the return of this command: `type(tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages=1,multiple_tables=True))`? I suspect, this is a list because of the `multiple_tables=True` option and you need to take the first item. If the return is `list`, please also provide the return of: `type(tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages=1,multiple_tables=True)[0])`

Comment: According to [tabula's documentation](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf), read_pdf returns a list. See my updated answer

Comment: Please, can you also give me the output of `pd.concat(tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages='all',multiple_tables=True))`?

Comment: Yes it return a list. `pd.concat(tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages='all',multiple_tables=True))` this is work